# Why is Date.prototype a Invalid Date, when Boolean.prototype is a Boolean {}?

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5

Environment:
- Chrome console

I understand:

```
Boolean.prototype; //Boolean {}
Number.prototype; //Number {}
```

I can't understand:

```
Date.prototype; //Invalid Date
```

Question:

- `Date` is different, why?
- `Date.prototype` does not exist?

```
Date.prototype.constructor; //function Date() { [native code] }
Date.prototype.constructor === Date; //true
```

Comment: because  alert(Date.prototype) is the same thing... it has to do with the default toString() method of Date()s, and what the method returns when this==undefined/NaN... note also how alert(+Date.prototype) shows NaN, the result of casting into a number.

Comment: By logging to console, you are triggering conversion into a string value, which implicitly calls the `toString` method. As [MDN tells us](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype), _“`Date.prototype.toString()` – Returns a string representing the specified Date object”_ – and that of course can’t be done with a non-existent Date value. To verify, do `Date.prototype.toString = function() { return "I’m toString :-)"; }; console.log(Date.prototype)`, and you’ll get `Date {I’m toString :-)}` as output …

Comment: ___Please___ don't use formatting like that again. Those special characters only make your question harder to read.

Comment: delete Date.prototype.toString; alert(Date.prototype); shows [object Date] instead.

Comment: *"15.9.5.2 Date.prototype.toString ( )
This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form."* http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.2 . Since `Date.prototype` is not a valid date on its own that's what you get.

Answer (score 1):

weird how everyone has put their answers into comments. anyway ...

As you saw by accessing `Date.prototype.constructor`, `Date.prototype` does exist. The `toString()` method for `Date` objects returns a human-readable form of the object.

As the language standard stipulates, the `toString` method is defined on the `Date.prototype`. Printing an object in the console first converts it to a string. Since the prototype itself is not a valid date, the method returns "Invalid Date."

You can also make an invalid date with `new Date(NaN)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because [the spec says so](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5):

> *The Date prototype object is itself a Date object (its `[[Class]]` is `"Date"`) whose `[[PrimitiveValue]]` is `NaN`.*

Objects like this are displayed as `Invalid Date` in your console (it show the result of calling the `toString` method) - `new Date(NaN)` would be as well. Clearly, `Date.prototype` *does* exist, it is an object and not `undefined`.

Similarly, "*The Boolean prototype object is itself a Boolean object (its `[[Class]]` is `"Boolean"`) whose value is `false`.*". There just is no special displaying for primitive-wrapper objects, so it is shown like a plain object that is constructed by the `Boolean` constructor.